# GWT request to download file

Tags: gwt, download

I know it's not possible to send an ajax request or use GWT's RequestBuidler to send a request for a file download; needing a form to do it but how do I get a reference to the response when it returns with lets say an error.

The request i send is for a file download but if the file download is too big the Java servlet responds with an error, how do i get a reference to this error to handle it appropriately on the GWT side.

Comment: You mean to upload a file to the server?

Comment: no download a file from server. Java servlet does the following,  resp.setContentType("application/csv; charset=utf-8;");
            resp.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + csvExportResult.attachmentName + ".csv\"");
... I can get it to work but if there is an error how do i get a reference to the response in GWT or javscript. Or is the target attribute on the form the only means of outputting the error text..which is being sent by the java servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler.html) to the form and parse the results in onSubmitComplete().

Answer (score 1):

With extGWT you can parse the HTML response to know the HTML error code

For instance

```
    com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.Component.addListener(Events.Submit, new Listener<FormEvent>()
    {
        public void handleEvent(final FormEvent event)
        {
            String htmlResponse = event.getResultHtml();

            (...)
        }
    });
```